# For loop in python - Can I loop a Variable?

Tags: python

I want to apply a specific code for a specific employee.

If I Search for Mark in a specific time range in the google calendar, I want the following code to run for Mark.

But instead, My code, runs for the first guy in the list, no matter his name. It is supposed to check for Mark!

This is a part of the code in question:

```
        currentEmployees = []
        for event in events:
            currentEmployees.append(event['summary'])

        if employee in currentEmployees:
            event_done = False
            event['summary'] = employee

            for event in events:
               if str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                event_done = False
                print(employee + ' is busy')
                break
               else:
                  event_done = True
                  break
```

So, if the employee that I chose in my list of employees, is inside `currentEmployees[]`, then it assign `event['summary']` to `employee` variable. But then, I do a `for event in events`, and this is where things don't work as intended anymore. It's suppose to check for EMPLOYEE in events... how do that I do that?

I want to apply this:

```
            for event in events:
               # if employee == event['summary']:
               if str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):
                event_done = False
                print(employee + ' est occupé')
                break
               else:
                  event_done = True
                  break
```

To the variable `employee`

this :
  `if str2datetime(currentStart) <= str2datetime(event['end']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]) and str2datetime(currentEnd) >= str2datetime(event['start']['dateTime'].split('+')[0]):`

simply checks if the added event overlap an existing one for the requested employee.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: `event['summary'] = employee` Is event a dict? What does the `events` variable have? One wrong thing that glares at me is this - `event['summary'] = employee`. When you do this `event` is already put of scope. I am not sure this will even compile unless some part of the code is not in the snippet provided.

Comment: If `events` is a dict, you are iterating over only the keys.

Comment: `events` are the appointments in the google calendar. If I wanna add an appointment the 10 July, it will check all the `events` in the 10th July. @leoOrion

Comment: Can you add an example of what the events variable would look like once populated

Comment: @leoOrion here you go! Check post again please..

Comment: I meant how it would look in code. Anywyas problem is mostly because of how you are iterating over your dict. See how a dict is to be iterated over